# turn Qt::MatchExactly to case insensitive

Tags: c++, qt

I am using `QT::MatchExactly` in my QStandardItemModel in the findItems method. I wanted to know is there anyway to turn it into case insensitive ?
Currently i have something like this:

```
mymodel->findItems("abc",Qt::MatchExactly,0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Qt::MatchFixedString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum):

```
mymodel->findItems("abc", Qt::MatchFixedString, 0);
```

The last parameter already defaults to 0, btw, so you can just write:

```
mymodel->findItems("abc", Qt::MatchFixedString);
```